# Read only given columns when streaming a parquet file in C++

Tags: c++, parquet

The [Parquet C++ documentation](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/cpp/parquet.html) gives this example to stream from a parquet file:

```
{
   std::shared_ptr<arrow::io::ReadableFile> infile;

   PARQUET_ASSIGN_OR_THROW(
      infile,
      arrow::io::ReadableFile::Open("test.parquet"));

   parquet::StreamReader stream{parquet::ParquetFileReader::Open(infile)};

   std::string article;
   float price;
   uint32_t quantity;

   while ( !stream.eof() )
   {
      stream >> article >> price >> quantity >> parquet::EndRow;
      // ...
   }
}
```

Suppose I want only to read price: how can I do that?
Is there a way to select which columns to read by name or by column number?

Comment: Maybe something like SkipColumns https://arrow.apache.org/docs/cpp/api/formats.html#_CPPv4N7parquet12StreamReader11SkipColumnsE7int64_t

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @kiner_shah for the comment, one can use the `skipColumns` method:

```
while ( !stream.eof() )
{ 
  stream.skipColumns(1);
  stream >> price;
  stream.skipColumns(1);
  stream >> parquet::EndRow;
  // ...
}
```

Comment: I think it should be `SkipColumns` and also last line should probably be `stream.EndRow()`.